# Multi Threaded GUI Java Socket Chat Application

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, user-interface, chat

I have written code for a chat room type application where the user can communicate with the server and the server can communicate with the user. But I want the server to be able to communicate with more than just one user. Can anyone help me with this as I've tried so much in the past couple of hours and got nowhere.

Here is my code for the client

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.sql.Time;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ClientChat extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static Socket socket;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField textField;
    JTextArea textArea;
    JButton button;

    public ClientChat() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        panel = new JPanel();
        textField = new JTextField();
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        button = new JButton("Send");
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        this.add(panel);
        textArea.setBounds(20, 20, 450, 360);
        panel.add(textArea);
        textField.setBounds(20, 400, 340, 30);
        panel.add(textField);
        button.setBounds(375, 400, 95, 30);
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 2000);

        textArea.setText("Connected to Server");
        this.setTitle("Client");
        while (true) {
            try {
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                String string = dis.readUTF();
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + '\n' + "Server:"
                        + string);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + '\n'
                        + "Message sending fail:Network Error");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if ((e.getSource() == button) && (textField.getText() != "")) {

            textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + '\n' + "User:"
                    + textField.getText());
            try {
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                        socket.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF(textField.getText());
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + '\n'
                        + "Message sending fail:Network Error");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            textField.setText("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
            IOException {
        ClientChat chatForm = new ClientChat();
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the Server

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ServerChat extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static ServerSocket server;
    static Socket socket;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField textField;
    JTextArea textArea;
    JButton button;
    DataInputStream dis;
    DataOutputStream dos;

    public ServerChat() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        panel = new JPanel();
        textField = new JTextField();
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        button = new JButton("Send");
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        this.add(panel);
        textArea.setBounds(20, 20, 450, 360);
        panel.add(textArea);
        textField.setBounds(20, 400, 340, 30);
        panel.add(textField);
        button.setBounds(375, 400, 95, 30);
        panel.add(button);
        this.setTitle("Server");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        server = new ServerSocket(2000, 1, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        textArea.setText("Waiting for Client");
        socket = server.accept();
        textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + '\n' + " Found");
        while (true) {
            try {
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                String string = dis.readUTF();
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + '\n' + "Client:"
                        + string);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + '\n'
                        + "Message sending fail:Network Error");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if ((e.getSource() == button) && (textField.getText() != "")) {
            textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + '\n' + "Server:"
                    + textField.getText());
            try {
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                        socket.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF(textField.getText());
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            textField.setText("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
    IOException {
        new ServerChat();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You need to have the `socket=server.accept()` code in a loop to service multiple requests simultaneously.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Comment: This isn't an answer as such, more general advice: multithreading in Java is not something that can be mastered in a matter of hours, or days even. But a decent start is [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). And you need to start simple, much simpler than a chat application. This may look like a step back from what you've achieved so far but trust me, if you persevere with it, you'll be in a much better position afterwards.